# How to encrypt nvarchar column in oracle?

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle11g, encryption-symmetric

I have a table containing `nvarchar`  datatype columns (contains text in different languages). I want to encrypt data before inserting into table and decrypt the same while fetching records.

Please suggest how i can achieve this.

Encryption and decryption should be done through a private key.

Hoping, my question is clear. Please confirm if i need to provide more information.

Comment: See: [Database Advanced Security Administrator's Guide / 3 Securing Stored Data Using Transparent Data Encryption](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asotrans.htm#g1011122) on Oracle Help Center.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thanks for your suggestion. I can not use Transparent data encryption as it is not available in standard edition.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it is probably wiser to crypt and decrypt your data directly in your application rather than in the database.

You can use Oracle's [DBMS_CRYPTO](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#BJFGFDFG) package. There is an [example](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#sthref1260) in the middle of the documentation page.

First you need to make a package to access the cipher type from SQL expression. Let's say you want AES256 in CBC mode with padding:

```
CREATE PACKAGE pkg_so_42979606
AS
    FUNCTION cipher_type RETURN PLS_INTEGER;
END pkg_so_42979606;
/
CREATE PACKAGE BODY pkg_so_42979606
AS
    ctype CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES256
                                  + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                                  + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
    FUNCTION cipher_type RETURN PLS_INTEGER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN ctype;
    END;
END pkg_so_42979606;
/
```

Then you will need a key. You can ask Oracle to generate one. To easily handle it I'll move it in Base64. Let's draw one:

```
DECLARE
    key_bytes_raw RAW(32);
    key_char NVARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    key_bytes_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.RANDOMBYTES(32);
    key_char := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(key_bytes_raw), 'AL32UTF8');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Key: ' || key_char);
END;
/
Key: pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=
```

Thus the cipher key I'll use is `pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=`.

Now I'll use a test table

```
CREATE TABLE so_42979606 (
    id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    data NVARCHAR2(2000));
```

You can insert encrypted data:

```
INSERT INTO so_42979606
    VALUES (1,
            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('My clear data', 'AL32UTF8'),
                                pkg_so_42979606.cipher_type(),
                                UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=', 'AL32UTF8'))));
```

And retrieve the encrypted data in clear.

```
SELECT id, UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_NCHAR(DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT(data,
                                    pkg_so_42979606.cipher_type(),
                                    UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('pMV3D4xhyfNxp3YyfLWzAErGcKkIjK3X6uc/WIeVTls=', 'AL32UTF8'))),
                                 'AL32UTF8') data
    FROM so_42979606;

ID DATA
-- ----------------------
 1 My clear data
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. trying same, returning Invalid data `???` when using nvarchar column with other languages text.

Comment: @Tajinder I edited to add a full blown example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Also note that if you relax your requirement to store the data in `RAW` columns then you will save some `UTL_I18N` casting.